# How to call function for every 1 min in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I just want to refresh my data in lightning component for every 1 mins. Like auto refresh. 
My test case like 'Want to display employees who are in inactive for every 1 min using Lightning component'

Answer (score 7):

You can create a function that you will call in init and in this function you need to add a setTimeout for 1 minute which will call this same function

```
controller :
doInit: function(component, event, helper){
   helper.everyMinute(component);
}

helper:
everyMinute:  function(component){
   var that = this;
   //put your code here and in setCallback add setTimeout with 1 minute

   var action = componet.get('c.getData');
   action.setCallback(this, function(result){
       //do your code
   });

   /* enqueue action in this way  */
   $A.enqueueAction(action);
    window.setTimeout(
        $A.getCallback(function() {
            console.log('Calling');
            that.everyMinute(component);
        }), 60000
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi @Imran Qureshi , Thanks for your quick reply.  But I am unable to refresh my page for specific time intervals. Did I make any mistake?Below is my code

Comment: Controller --> doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.getAssignedEmpList(component);
    }

Comment: Helper -->getAssignedEmpList: function(component) {
        var that = this;
        var action = component.get("c.getAssignedEmps");
        action.setCallback(this, function(result) {
            component.set("v.assignedEmps", result.getReturnValue());  
            setTimeout((function(){
                that.getAssignedEmpList(component);
            }), 10000);
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }

Comment: @Ajay try the updated code to call action

Comment: $A.run is not function error..

Comment: @Ajay Please [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/137817/edit) your question with the code you tried.

Comment: @ImranQureshi `$A.run()` is deprecated so it won't work.Also wrap the `setTimeout()` with in `$A.getCallback()`. you find more info about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_mod_ext_js.htm)

Comment: @Praveen thanks for suggestion.
Ajay Try updated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use setTimeout or setInterval with $A.getCallback()

Comment: This is the second one of your posts that I found in the "Low Quality Posts" review queue. I hope you don't take this the wrong way, but it would help if you could add more explanation to your answers.